# Does CSVHelper handle overflow of files?

Tags: .net, csvhelper

What happens when CSVHelper appends too many records and exceeds the file size limit for a standard Win10 system? Will CSVHelper overflow to another file? How does this logic work or do I have to write my own? Thank you!

Comment: @Jens: The tag says it. It's a .NET library.

Comment: What file size limit?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by *file size limit*.  FAT32 filesystems have a file size limit of [4 GB](https://superuser.com/q/440509) while [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) filesystems have a limit of 16 TB (Win 7) to 8 PB or more (Win 10).  Are you actually hitting these limits somehow?

Comment: Yes, I might be potentially logging to a csv file for an extended amount of time. Edited for Win 10 system.

Comment: On windows 10 a single file can be up to 8 PB ([source](https://superuser.com/q/1365534)) or roughly 8000 Terabytes.  You're going to run out of disk space before you hit that limit on any reasonable "standard Win10 system".  When CsvHelper tries to write to a stream and there is not enough disk space left, an `IOException` should get thrown as explained e.g. in the docs for [`Stream.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.write).  This might hypothetically result in the last record getting truncated.

Comment: And as far as I know CsvHelper doesn't have some built-in logic to write to a different file on a different disk when the original file runs out of space.

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using a logging library like [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/), [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).  They all have the ability to start another logging file after a file reaches a certain size or even create a new one daily.  You can also set them to remove logging files after a certain time period so you don't completely fill up your disk space.

Comment: Considering that the constructors of `CsvWriter` only accept a `TextWriter` and not paths it would be very surprising if it's silently creating and swapping in a second `TextWriter` (which it somehow would know should be file-backed and give an appropriate name) upon encountering an error instead of just propagating that error and letting you, the consumer, decide how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

`CsvHelper.CsvWriter` takes in a `TextWriter` and doesn't know anything about files, or the destination of the data it's writing. You would need to monitor the file size and stop writing when it reaches your limit and start a new file.